# How to get unique/distinct count from $reduce within $expr of a find query?

Tags: mongodb

In my collection, I have documents which contains an array (called `values`) of objects, which has `id` and `val` fields. The data looks like this

```
[
  {
    values: [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "456",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "789",
        "val": false
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    values: [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": false
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    values: [
      {
        "id": "234",
        "val": false
      },
      {
        "id": "567",
        "val": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to query this data by `val` to ensure it is `true`, and there may be cases where I want to ensure that an `array` has 2 instances of `val`'s that is `true`. I am able to achieve this with the following query:

```
db.collection.find({
  values: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      val: true
    }
  },
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$values",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.val",
                      true
                    ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      2
    ]
  }
})
```

The results of the query above give me the following result:

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "456",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "789",
        "val": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The issue with this now, is that I want to ensure that there are no duplicate `id`'s in the results of the `$reduce`'d list. I have researched the docs and [`$group`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) looks promising, however I am unsure on how to integrate this into the query.
I want the result to look like the following:

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "456",
        "val": true
      },
      {
        "id": "789",
        "val": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is a [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5lRmcaagSWH) link with all of the above in it.

**Please Note**

I have simplified the code examples here to get to the core of the problem. In my actual use case, there are many values of different data types, which means that using an $elemMatch is the best way to go for me.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [Takis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792662/how-to-get-unique-distinct-count-from-reduce-within-expr-of-a-find-query/74792880#74792880), it made me realise that using `$setUnion` is an alternative way to find the distinct values of a field. Using this, I was able to rework my query to achieve what I want.

What I have done to achieve this is to have a `$cond` operator within the `$expr` operator. I pass in the original `$reduce` as the condition to see if `x` amount of `val`'s appear within the document. If it succeeds, then I am ensuring that the size of the union of `values.id`'s (i.e. all the unique id's within the current document `values` array) is at least `x` amount. If this condition is satisfied, the document will be returned. If not, then it falls back to the value `false`, i.e. it will not return the current document.

The query is as follows:

```
db.collection.find({
  values: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      val: true
    }
  },
  $expr: {
    $cond: [
      {
        $gte: [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$values",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: {
                $sum: [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.val",
                          true
                        ]
                      },
                      1,
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          2 // x amount of instances
        ]
      },
      {
        $gte: [
          {
            "$size": {
              $setUnion: [
                "$values.id"
              ]
            }
          },
          2 // x amount of instances
        ]
      },
      false
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is a [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MsvSqFmEYdg) link showing it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- reduce is fine, but maybe 2 filters are simpler here
- first filter to have `true count >=2`
- second filter to not have duplicate id, by comparing the `values.id` length, with the length of the set `values.id` (keep it only if same size else => duplicate), it works using `paths on arrays = arrays like values.id is array of ids`

*if this is slow for your use case maybe it can be faster

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63993047424f6130d7f1217e)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$and": 
       [{"$gte": 
           [{"$size": {"$filter": {"input": "$values.val", "cond": "$$this"}}},
            2]},
         {"$eq": 
           [{"$size": "$values.id"},
             {"$size": {"$setUnion": ["$values.id", []]}}]}]}}}])
```

Comment: Whilst that does work, my question was specifically about if you could do it within find? Is it better to use aggregate vs find?

Comment: aggregate or find doesn't matter, you can put the find inside the $match, but `$expr` has limited support on index use only some aggregate operators can use index [see doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#behavior) but those you need can't be done with query operators i think, so you need aggregate operators.